# Why there is a margin on the top of a text?

Tags: html, css

When including text in a div , i found a slight margin on top of the text.How to get rid of the margin ?

```html
<html>
  <style>
   #box{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:50px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#ffffff;
   }
  </style>
  <body>
  <div id="box">TEXT</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The space between the top of the text and red box? That's the natural `line-height`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
  <style>
   #box{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:50px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
                line-height:38px; /* reduce line height for desired results */
    color:#ffffff;
   }
  </style>
  <body>
  <div id="box">TEXT</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The same as for the other answer, setting the line-height to a value smaller than the font-size may cause you to loose some of the actual text. Use carefully.

Comment: Absolutely. I'd say if you're tweaking line-height like this, you should probably rethink your entire approach. This will have really nasty effects as well if your text ever starts wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `line-height`. I have it set here to have no space.

```
#box{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:50px;
    line-height: 33px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not something you can blindly do. It is related to the font. When you make the line height smaller than the font size, changes are you will lose part of the text. It may fit exactly for this font on this device, but a different device might display it slightly different or may fall back to a different font, and you may loose too much of the text. Not a big problem, maybe, but something to take into account, and something an answer like this should warn about.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree. A better approach would be to have the text in its own element and then manipulate its position. If that text was continue onto a new line it would overlap and look terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `line-height` indeed to reduce gap on top and beneath the text, but  maybe you should use **`em`** values to have this more reliable.

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  line-height: 0.65em;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
div:hover {
  font-family: courier;
}
span {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: courier;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">TEXT<span>text</span>
</div>
```